# javascript after import variable Cannot access before initialization

Tags: javascript

why I can log the imported variable but it show undefined when I added to another variable.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import log from './log.js';
export var test = 'Hello';
log();
```

log.js

```
import { test } from './index.js';
var x = test + '  Word'
export default function log() {
    console.log(test);
    console.log(x);
}
```

console log

```
Hello
undefined  Word
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In log.js you need to initialize var **"x"** in the function. This will work, I tested.

```
import { test } from './index.js';
export default function log() {
  var x = test + '  Word'
  console.log(test);
  console.log(x);
}
```